# Почему в python3 зависает paramiko?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, paramiko

```
def connect(target, sshport, user, password):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    try:
        ssh.connect(target, port = sshport, username = user, password = password, timeout=5, banner_timeout = 5, auth_timeout=5)
        resultCode = 1
    except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
        resultCode = 0
    except socket.error:
        resultCode = 2
```

В некоторых случаях (в каких именно - не установленно, сложновоспроизводимо))зависает в этой строчке:

```
ssh.connect(target, port = sshport, username = user, password = password, timeout=5, banner_timeout = 5, auth_timeout=5)
```

Comment: Тайм-аут может, не дожидался?

Comment: а зачем вам `banner_timeout` и `auth_timeout`? И что именно вы имеете ввиду под "зависает"?